# The Component 'SidebarComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule angular 9

Tags: components, angular9

I have created a component called sidebar.component.ts that I am including in two other modules (abc and def).

abc.module.ts

```
import {SidebarComponent} from './../sidebar/sidebar.component';
@NgModule({
   declarations: [SidebarComponent],
   schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

def.module.ts

```
import {SidebarComponent} from './../sidebar/sidebar.component';
@NgModule({
   declarations: [SidebarComponent],
   schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

When I redirect one page in abc module to another page in def module, it is throwing me following error.

- error NG6007: The Component 'SidebarComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `shared.module`, declare and export your `SidebarComponent` in this module, finally Import `SharedModule` every `@NgModule` you want.